# How to get sum with date filtering and distinct with EF?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

In my system I have a table with participants weight history (ParticipantData):

```
ParticipantId  Weight    Date
1              86        2020-01-30
1              83        2020-02-03
2              98        2020-01-20
2              96        2020-01-26
3              75        2020-02-06
```

I need to get the sum of weights, but a participant must only count one time with their latest weight before or equal to a specific date.

Here's what I have so far:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
DateTime? chartStartDate = new DateTime(Event.Event.StartDateTime.Value.Year, Event.Event.StartDateTime.Value.Month, Event.Event.StartDateTime.Value.Day);
DateTime? chartEndDate = dt < Event.Event.EndDateTime ? dt : Event.Event.EndDateTime;
bool chartLoop = true;

if (chartStartDate < dt) {
    // Get all weights
    var participantsWeightStats = await _context.ParticipantData.ToListAsync();
    // Loop date with steps of 7
    do {
        // Get the sum of `participantsWeightStats` before or equal to the loop-date
        // In the following I need to Distinct/GroupBy ParticipantId so every participant only counts with the latest weight 
        var chartData = participantsWeightStats.Where(x => x.Date <= chartStartDate).OrderByDescending(x => x.Date).ToList();
        ViewData["PData_Values"] += chartData.Sum(x => x.Weight).ToString().Replace(".", "").Replace(",", ".") + ",";
        ViewData["PData_Labels"] += "'" + chartStartDate.Value.ToString("d") + "',";
        chartStartDate = chartStartDate.Value.AddDays(7);
        if (chartStartDate > chartEndDate && chartLoop) {
            chartStartDate = chartEndDate;
            chartLoop = false;
        }
    } while (chartStartDate <= chartEndDate);
}
```

I've tried different approaches with GroupBy and Distinct but with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("ParticipantId", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Weight", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {1, 86, DateTime.Parse("2020-01-30")});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {1, 83, DateTime.Parse("2020-02-03")});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {2, 98, DateTime.Parse("2020-01-20")});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {2, 96, DateTime.Parse("2020-01-26")});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {2, 75, DateTime.Parse("2020-02-06")});

            DateTime endDate = DateTime.Parse("2020-01-31");

            int sum = dt.AsEnumerable()
                .Where(x => x.Field<DateTime>("Date") <= endDate)
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.Field<DateTime>("Date"))
                .GroupBy(x => x.Field<int>("ParticipantId"))
                .Sum(x => x.First().Field<int>("Weight"));


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @jdweng. The `First()` in the SUM was what I couldn't figure out. When I tried I could not get the Weight when grouping. But can you see from my question, if I'm doing something wrong? I believe I get the wrong results. Every 7th day gives about the same weight sum and I know that isn't the fact.

Comment: It may have to do with timezone.  The end date is midnight.  So if the times were taken in a different timezone than the end date is cutting off the dates incorrectly.  Suppose you were in PST and the data was collect in EST.  Than data in EST collected at 1:00AM is PST 10:00PM.  Then depending on the end data this sample may be included or not included.

Comment: I see, but I don't think that's the case. I know from another calculation, that the total weighloss is around 3000 kilos. When I do the loop, the first sum gives me ~95000 (the sum of participants weight the first day). That might be right. But the following 7-days steps is all around 110000 and that's not true.

Comment: After some testing I can see, that the query is summing all a participants weights before or equal to the loop-date - it should only get the latest.

Comment: The there is something wrong with your date.  The code I posted is getting a sum of 86 + 96 = 182.  If you only want a week then you need both a start date and an end date.

Comment: The code is summing the latest from each ParticipantId.  If the GroupBy is not working you will also get wrong results.

Comment: I can't use startdate/enddate, because I don't know when participants entered their latest weight. Every step should calculate the latest weight no matter when it is entered. When I output the data in the query, every participant only appears 1 time per loop, but with all weights before the loop-date summed.

Comment: My code works if the dates are DataTime (not string).  Not sure why you are not getting correct answer.